# MyBB redirects to www.www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mybb

I am working on setting up a MyBB forum with https enabled. I've got TLS set up and enabled and https redirect is enabled by my host.

Direct links like `http://www.example.com/index.php` and `example.com/index.php` correctly redirect to `https://www.example.com/index.php`. But any any attempts to go straight to to `https://www.example.com/` go to `https://www.www.example.com/`. Does anyone have any ideas about what might cause this?

My .htaccess file is as follows (mostly taken from MyBB's default .htaccess setup.)

```
    Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(php|html)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>



#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RedirectMatch ^/$ news.php

    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>


#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html application/xhtml+xml text/xml application/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/json application/manifest+json application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/font-sfnt application/font-woff application/font-woff2 image/svg+xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>

# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
<Files "error.log">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a browser caching issue.